# What is the difference between std::cout and std::wcout?

Tags: c++, cout

In c++ what is the difference between `std::cout` and `std::wcout`?

They both control output to a stream buffer or print stuff to the console, or are they just alike ?

Comment: The w versions of standard streams are for **w**ide characters.

Comment: They don't "print to the console".  They write to stdout.  Often, stdout is associated with a tty.  Sometimes (rarely), the terminal you are using is a console.  Don't conflate stdout with the terminal, and don't refer to your terminal as a "console".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

They operate on different character types:

- `std::cout` uses `char` as character type
- `std::wcout` uses `wchar_t` as character type

Otherwise both streams write to standard output.

Comment: but what are wide characters any way?

Comment: `char` is used for *narrow* strings, suitable for 7-bit ASCII and 8-bit ANSI.  `wchar_t` is used for *wide* strings, aka Unicode strings. However, the size of `wchar_t` is not portable, on some systems it is 16bit (suitable for UCS2/UTF-16), on others it is 32bit (suitable for UCS4/UTF-32). C++11 introduced new `char16_t` and `char32_t` types to deal with that descrepency.

Comment: Does cout and wcout have their own buffer ？

Comment: @xusisme I would guess they’d have different buffers as they store characters of different types and the `std::basic_streambuf` abstraction doesn’t handle chatacter encodings on this level. I don’t think there is defined synchronization between the narrow and wide character streams, i.e., alternately writing to each if them may cause blocks of characters being written, although with `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(true)` (the default) the characters are still not buffered.

Comment: @DietmarKühl So, what happens if I mix cout and wcout ?

Comment: @xusisme: as I said: I don't thin there is a defined order between them. If `sync_with_stdio(false)` was called, I would expect characters to be emitted in blocks from `std::cout` and `std::wcout`. With `sync_with_stdio(true)` the same may happen but I would guess that for most implementations things interleave the way they are written as `sync_with_stdio(true)` typically disables buffering of the standard streams.

Answer (score 6):

Another thing is that both are used with respected input stream.

Objects of these are initialized during or before the first time an object of `std::ios_base::Init` is created.

- `std::cout` is `std::basic_ios::tie`'d to `std::cin` and to `std::cerr`
- `std:wcout` is `std::basic_ios::tie`'d to `std::wcin` and to `std::wcerr`